# Sharepoint broke Active Directory?

Tags: user-profile, active-directory, user-profile-service

Have a bit of a urgent issue here and hope I can get some advice.

I suspect that somehow Sharepoint 2010 User Profile Sync overwrote certain active directory properties with null or empty values.

I notified this morning that in Active Director, my Manager property for most users is blank! My Manager property is set to export so I would expect that it would change it in AD if a user changes his manager, but would Sharepoint really be able to clear out everyone's Manager field? I doubt if it's possible, but it seems to have happened.

Is there a place where I can check whether this is true or not?

Everything was working fine until a couple of days ago. The sync was writing back to AD only changed values.

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Did you already checked the ULS logs for the Category "User Profile"?? Additionally, you could force a Syncronization and use the miisclient.exe to watch what is going on.

Comment: I'm checking in Active Directory and the actual Manager Attribute/field is no longer showing (using Softerra Ldap browser)

Comment: SharePoint does not mess with the Schema, but with the values. Export action only updates it.

Comment: I also suspect some other script or program messing around with the schema because SharePoint never changes anything but the values.

Comment: Ok.. is there any place to see what Sharepoint tried to update? Does UPS log somewhere?

Comment: Yes, go for ULSViewer tool on MSDN and open up your Logs files (hoping you've configured http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/tabid/40/entryid/190/All-About-SharePoint-2010-ULS-Logging.aspx).

Comment: I know ULSviewer but i dont think Sharepoint logs user profile sync changes there... does it?

Comment: you can also look at the logs for the MIISClient. It will show what happend for every step.